# Ubuntu 14.04 : How do you use mount.cifs, mount.nfs, they are not in the repositories any more?

Tags: 14.04, mount, nfs, cifs

In Ubuntu 12 LTS, I always used **mount.cifs** and **mount.nfs**

Now they are not in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository, so how do you use mount cifs and mount nfs or install them in 14?

Thanks

i.e.)

Ubuntu 12.04 always worked with:

```
 root@ub12box# mount -t cifs -o user=administrator '\\192.168.0.1\Data' /tmp/myServer ; df ;
 Password: ***************
 Filesystem                1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted
 on /dev/sdb2                 144636 85800  26058836  8% /
 \\192.168.0.1\Data 8059772 652288 407484  6% /tmp/myServer
```

But doesnt work in Ubuntu 14.04 machine same command:

```
root@ub14box# mount -t cifs -o user=administrator '\\192.168.0.1\Data' /tmp/myServer ; df ;
mount: block device \\192.168.0.1\Data is write-protected, mounting read-only 
mount: cannot mount block device \\192.168.0.1\Data read-only

Filesystem                1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted
on /dev/sdb2                 126636 950900  99958936  2% /

root@ub14box# dmesg|tail
[ 2023.664186] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 2023.664197] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 2023.667124] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
[ 2023.676417] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[ 2023.676424] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[ 2023.676499] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

Comment: It just worked for me on 14.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `mount.cifs` command is provided by `cifs-utils` and `mount.nfs` by `nfs-common`.

In general, when you're looking for a particular file and don't know which package provides it, you can search in the [Ubuntu Repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) or in `synaptic`. Alternatively, you can use `apt-file`.

If it is not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install apt-file` and then update its database with `apt-file update`. Once you've done that, you can easily search package contents:

```
$ apt-file search mount.cifs mount.nfs
cifs-utils: /sbin/mount.cifs
cifs-utils: /usr/share/man/man8/mount.cifs.8.gz
$ apt-file search mount.nfs
manpages-fr-extra: /usr/share/man/fr/man8/mount.nfs.8.gz
manpages-fr-extra: /usr/share/man/fr/man8/umount.nfs.8.gz
nfs-common: /sbin/mount.nfs
nfs-common: /sbin/mount.nfs4
nfs-common: /sbin/umount.nfs
nfs-common: /sbin/umount.nfs4
nfs-common: /usr/share/man/man8/mount.nfs.8.gz
nfs-common: /usr/share/man/man8/umount.nfs.8.gz
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was VERY HELPFUL! I appreciate it very much!!!

Comment: One more question. After installing these packages I noticed that my machine now has ports open for **rpcbind**, and **rpc.statd**. Can I disable these to close these ports somehow?

Comment: @Bran I'm sure you can but I don't know how off the top of my head. You could post that as a new question.

Comment: Found it: /etc/init.d/rpcbind and /sbin/rpcbind <-- I just renamed these and rebooted, and now server has no rpcbind capability. Thanks so much!